# assign values to numeric indexed multidimensional array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

i want to loop a jquery selector using .each() and assign values to a multidimensional array $record.
here is what i tried and it doesnt work

JQUERY:

```
var $record = new Array(),
    i=0,
    x,y;
$("td").each(function(){       
    x = Math.floor((i+1)/4),
    y = i%4;
    $record[x][y] = true;    
    i++;
});
```

CHROME CONSOLE ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Comment: That is one strange looking array, can't imagine how you'd access that and figure out the keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is raising because you did not define the inner array.

Try,

```
$("td").each(function(){       
    x = Math.floor((i+1)/4),
    y = i%4;
    if(!$.isArray($record[x])) { $record[x] = []; }
    $record[x][y] = true;    
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this

```
var record = [],
    i = 0,
    x = Math.floor((i+1)/4),
    y = Math.floor((i+1)/4)

console.log(record); // 0
console.log(record[0]); // undefined
console.log(record[x][y]); // Uncaught TypeError: 
                           // Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

First iteration, `i` is `0`. You're trying to access an element that doesn't exist. Or to be even more specific, the property `0` on the array, which would exist if there was an element on index `0`.

In other words, if you add something to the array, it would get it's property:

```
record[0] = 'something';
console.log(record['0'], record.hasOwnProperty('0')); // 'something', true
```